# References from JabRef not importing to LyX

Tags: biblatex

I have a .bib file made in JabRef that I am trying to use in a Lyx file.  I have inserted the "BibTeX Generated Bibliography" at the end of the LyX file.  However, when I try to include a citation, the list of available citations does not include all the references in my .bib file; the list only includes older ones.  Any help on how to access all references in the .bib file would be much appreciated.

Comment: Resolved-turns out I had an error in my .bib file (some unrecognized black box character)!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was resolved by the OP themselves (see comment above). It's close to impossible to find out what might have been wrong from the details shared so far in the question (plus the entire setup is unlcear), so the Q&A is unlikely to help future visitors.